# Instagram Comment Scraping, Scrapes Username instead of comment

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So I am trying to scrape usernames and comments from multiple posts. Using this code below.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import sys
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import os.path
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains



url=['https://www.instagram.com/p/CRLe53_hmMH','https://www.instagram.com/p/CRX7VL1sL54/?utm_medium=share_sheet',
     'https://www.instagram.com/p/CRVB7ykM7-R/?utm_medium=share_sheet', 'https://www.instagram.com/p/CRQ9Bq5M6ce/?utm_medium=share_sheet',
     'https://www.instagram.com/p/CRQT1BJMmSi/?utm_medium=share_sheet', 'https://www.instagram.com/p/CM8T3HgMQG0/?utm_medium=copy_link'
     'https://www.instagram.com/p/COrn5fYs78O/?utm_medium=share_sheet']
user_names = []
user_comments = []
driver = driver = webdriver.Chrome('E:/chromedriver')
driver.get(url[0])
time.sleep(3)
username = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='username']")))
password = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='password']")))
username.clear()
username.send_keys('myuname')
password.clear()
password.send_keys('mypassword')
Login_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[type='submit']"))).click()
        
time.sleep(4)
not_now = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[contains(text(), "Not Now")]'))).click()
not_now2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[contains(text(), "Not Now")]'))).click()
for n in url:
    try:
        driver.get(n)
        time.sleep(3)
        load_more_comment = driver.find_element_by_class_name('glyphsSpriteCircle_add__outline__24__grey_9')
        print("Found {}".format(str(load_more_comment)))
        i = 0
        while load_more_comment.is_displayed() and i < 10:
            load_more_comment.click()
            time.sleep(1.5)
            load_more_comment = driver.find_element_by_class_name('glyphsSpriteCircle_add__outline__24__grey_9')
            print("Found {}".format(str(load_more_comment)))
            i += 1
            
        
        user_names.pop(0)
        user_comments.pop(0)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass  
    comment = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('gElp9 ')
    for c in comment:
        container = c.find_element_by_class_name('C4VMK')
        name = container.find_element_by_class_name('_6lAjh ').text
        content = container.find_element_by_tag_name('span').text
        content = content.replace('\n', ' ').strip().rstrip()
        user_names.append(name)
        user_comments.append(content)
        print(content)
    user_names.pop(0)
    user_comments.pop(0)
          
    
    
    
    #export(user_names, user_comments)
    
driver.close()
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(user_names, user_comments)),
               columns =['Name', 'Comments'])
#df.to_excel('ujicoba_gabung_IG_6.xlsx')
print(df)
```

But somehow instead of returning username and comment, both user_names and user_comments return usernames. Where did I make a mistake?

Here Are My outputs

[image]

I think my problem is on the for loop where I declare the container as C4VMK. But I inspected the element on Instagram it is already the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two `span` in `C4VMK` class. First in `h3 -> first div -> span` and second is that one you want.
For getting the second `span` that is the comment, replace your code with below and get the second element.

```
content = container.find_elements_by_tag_name('span')[1].text
```

Answer (score 0):

Your container is correct. However, when you search for a span by tag name like this:

```
content = container.find_element_by_tag_name('span').text
```

Selenium will find the first span that is under the content. Which in this case is the username span with the class 'Jv7Aj mArmR MqpiF  '.

[image]

What you are looking for is the other span that I highlighted in the image, which is a direct child of the container with an empty class.

You can select it like this:

```
content = container.find_element_by_xpath("/span[@class='']")
```